# using prototypes to change inbuilt methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, prototype

I have three questions and all of them are related.

1) I want to add a property called `bar` to `String` object.
I did this

```
String.prototype.bar=function() {console.log("jjjj");}
"mystring.bar//function()
"mystring".bar()//jjjj
```

but I want to use `"mystring".bar` (no function call) just like how we use `"mystring".length` to get the length of string. how can I acheive this?

2) now I want to change the inbuilt method of length on String object. so I did this

```
>>> String.prototype.length=function(){console.log("xxx");};
function()
>>> "mmmm".length
4
```

but the length method has not changed. it still returns the length of string only.
Note: I am changing this method only on console for learning purposes

3) I am having difficulty understanding this function from the book, `javascript, the good parts by Crockford.`(pg no 40)
here is the method to augment String object. It replace HTML entities in a string and replace them with their equivalents

```
String.method('deentityify',function() {
var entity =  {
quot:'";,
lt:'<',
gt:'<'
};
//return the deentityify method
return function() {
  return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g,
         function (a,b) {
         var r = entity[b];
         return typeof r==='string' ? r : a;
        }
     );
   };
}());
'&lt;&quot;&gt;'.dentityify();//<">
```

questions on this problem:
1)since no prototpye is used, does this method is available on all String objects to be used.

2)in the `return this.replace(..` part of the above, I do not understand what parameters are given to `a and b.` ie when I call '`&lt;&quot;&gt;'.dentityify();`, what does `a and b` get and how that anonymous function is executed.

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use "mystring".bar (no function call) just like how we use "mystring".length to get the length of string. how can I acheive this?

Assuming you want to use a function to compute some value dynamically, but want to use the syntax of a normal property access, not a function, you have to create a getter property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'bar', {
    get: function() {
        return 'jjjjj';
    }
});
```

> but the length method has not changed. it still returns the length of string only.

That's because [`.length` is not a writeable property](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5.1):

> Once a String object is created, this property is unchanging. It has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`.

---

> I do not understand what parameters are given to `a` and `b` [...] and how that anonymous function is executed

The callback is executed internally by [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for each match found by the regular expression. What the arguments are is explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The first argument is the whole match and each following argument is the value of one of the capture groups in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding (1) - don't use `function`, assign property directly to prototype:

```
String.prototype.bar = "bar from string prototype";
alert('some text'.bar); // "bar from string prototype"
```

Regarding (2) - I don't think this is possible.

Regarding (3) Crockford defines `.method` as:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
   return this;
};
```

So it's a custom implementation designed to hide using of the `prototype`